# PHP script for posting/voting links?

Tags: php

I'm looking for a php script/system that can let users login/register, post links, vote on links. Are there any open source project doing that?

I'm looking for something similar like reddit.com or dzone.com.

Cheers.

Comment: *"Are there any open source project doing that?"* - Yes

Comment: @Fred -ii-: put it as an answer please

Comment: Can you tell me the name?

Comment: LOL! @zerkms I'm almost tempted.

Comment: @Fred -ii-: terrible answer for a terrible question, fair deal :-)

Comment: Works out, it scratched my back and I scratched back! lol @zerkms

Comment: It's unfair to close my question. check out this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10562715/php-login-registration-user-management-script

Comment: Depends on the time of day/night I guess. The night crew's been coding all day, best to ask this at the crack of dawn sometimes. @Ryan

Comment: @Ryan: we're going to close it now actually

Comment: I have been searching for quite a while, just want to get a answer here. Please be lenient

Comment: "just want to get a answer here" --- unfortunately SO isn't a google for projects. It's a community for developers.

Comment: @Ryan SO is not for recommending tools

Comment: @Ryan The fact that the question you link to isn't closed doesn't mean that your questions shouldn't be closed, it just means that both should be. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 3):

As per Zerkms's request.

*"Are there any open source project doing that?"* - Yes

On a more serious note, here is a list of some of the (script) resources which have helped me in the past. You will find many good and free scripts that will get you up and going with your project.

- http://www.hotscripts.com/
- http://www.resourceindex.com/
- http://php.resourceindex.com/
- http://www.tizag.com/
- http://phpro.org/tutorials/Object-Oriented-Programming-with-PHP.html
- http://code.tutsplus.com/categories/php
- http://www.91weblessons.com/mysql-prepared-statements-with-php/
- http://php.net
- http://mysql.com

and an `mysqli` method: http://w3epic.com/php-mysql-login-system-a-super-simple-tutorial/

However in the link just above, where they have:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
```

I would make it as:

```
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['username']);
```

etc. (just to be on the safe side)

There are a few links that are a good read, in regards to security that I feel you should also be made aware of when putting something together as such:

- [**How to prevent SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/)
- [**On Owasp.org**](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-Top_10)

Plus, do use the latest password technology and not storing them as plain text like many do today.

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt (bcrypt)
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php (PHP's password hashing)

Always hash (and salt) passwords, not encrypt; remember that.

Comment: can you provide the link?

Comment: The question was closed with a mix of being too broad a question, or asking for a tool/library and those are pretty much off-limit here. This type of question consists of many different pieces of code put together, PHP, HTML, MySQL and the list goes on. You just need to really Google the the words you've put in your question and it will yield many results, I can guarantee it. @Ryan

Comment: On a more serious note, I added a few websites in my answer that have proved extremely useful to me in the past, I now code everything by hand now, so I rarely go there anymore. @Ryan

Comment: And this one looks promising http://w3epic.com/php-mysql-login-system-a-super-simple-tutorial/ which has also been listed in my answer. I hope it all helps as much as they have for me. @Ryan